# Problems : live updating labels/progress bars using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do a small iOS app to visually prove the big number's law.

How it is supposed to work?

---

A function finds a **random number** (based on an **interval given by the user**, using the `UIStepper`) and **check if it is equal to 1**, for a **number of times also given by the user** (using the `UISlider`). If it is equal to 1, it then increments a variable. At the end, **it gives the percentage of 1** after the whole loop is processed.

What's the problem then?

---

First of all, **the UIProgressBar isn't moving** through the process, and goes all the way up to 100% at the end. The main label **is supposed to show the value in real time** if the Switch is on, but it doesn't **(the switch state does nothing)**. And - last but not least -  if you select the maximum value of the `UISlider`, after the process is finished, **you can't start again**.
You can check its
[User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJfZD.png)
to get a better idea of it.

This is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Outlets :
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var processingSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var probStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var probSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMax: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPossibilties: UILabel!

    //Actions :
    @IBAction func refreshValues(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        probSlider.setValue(1, animated: true)
        probStepper.value = 2
        labelMax.text = String(probSlider.value)
        labelPossibilties.text = String(probStepper.value)
    }
    @IBAction func probaSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {labelMax.text = String(Double(Int(probSlider.value)))}
    @IBAction func probaStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {labelPossibilties.text = String(UInt32(probStepper.value))}
    @IBAction func mainButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {bigNumbersLaw(processingSwitch.isOn, UInt32(probStepper.value), Double(Int(probSlider.value)))}

    //Variables :
    var repeatNumber:Double = 0
    var randomNumber:UInt32 = 0
    var probability:Double = 0
    var timesFound:Double = 0

    //Functions :
    func bigNumbersLaw(_ liveShow: Bool, _ poss: UInt32, _ max: Double) {

        while repeatNumber < max {
            repeatNumber += 1
            randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(poss)
            progressBar.progress = Float(repeatNumber/max)
            if randomNumber == 1 {
                timesFound += 1
            }
            probability = (timesFound/repeatNumber)
            if liveShow {mainLabel.text = String(probability)}
        }
        mainLabel.text = String(probability)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        probStepper.maximumValue = 1000000
        probStepper.minimumValue = 2
        probSlider.maximumValue = 1000000
        probSlider.minimumValue = 1
    }
}
```

Thank you some much to anyone that can help me, and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with the fact, that there is no layout/drawing pass during the execution of your `bigNumbersLaw` method. Since this method is called synchronously, there are no UI updates until it executes itself, and when the next frame is being drawn it uses the latest values set.

What you need to do, is to "break down" this execution into steps, and update the UI between them.

```
//Functions :
func bigNumbersLaw(_ liveShow: Bool, _ poss: UInt32, _ max: Double) { // #3

    if repeatNumber < max { // #1
        repeatNumber += 1
        randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(poss)
        progressBar.progress = Float(repeatNumber/max)
        if randomNumber == 1 {
            timesFound += 1
        }
        probability = (timesFound/repeatNumber)
        mainLabel.text = String(probability)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(1)) {
            bigNumbersLaw(liveShow, poss, max) // #2
        }
    }
}
```

Bear in mind - I haven't tested this code, but it should work. Two main things happened here :

1. The loop got changed for a simple `if` check.
2. The "loop" is now executed here. We dispatch the next "turn of the loop" to be executed `1` milisecond in the future - this will allow the system to update the UI.

I've removed the `liveShow` variable from the code, since I couldn't find an elegant solution to fit it - this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Another note - you should probably block the UI while this is being executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks to your "loop", I managed to fix the problems with the UIProgressBar, and the mainLabel. I also succeeded in blocking the UI, and with the processingSwitch. **But there's still** a problem going on with the "max" value, although I tested a few different things. When you change its value using the UISlider, **the loop restarts from the latest max value** and goes all the way up to the new one. In addition, **it starts from the latest probability** value too.

Comment: Do you reset these values anywhere in your code? You should do it in your `mainButton` handler method, before calling `bigNumbersLaw` so that they are all `0` on each press of the button.

Comment: I forgot about it, what a stupid problem! Thank you so much for your help! Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your changes of the GUI on the main thread?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
   // your UI update code
}
```

Changes of the GUI are should always be called on the main thread ([GCD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch)). This would apply in all your IBActions and when you want the slider to animate/move.

A very good read about it [Grand Central Dispatch - Joyce Matos on Medium](https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/grand-central-dispatch-swift-3-93f995c15fd2)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! In fact, using a DispatchQueue cause a NSException, but I had already tried it (sorry for not mentioning that). I did put it within my function, with those two lines inside : `probability = (timesFound/repeatNumber)
        if liveShow {mainLabel.text = String(probability)}`

Comment: The method that does the UI updates is called from an `@IBAction` and these are always called on the main thread.